Как отвалидировать файлы в Laravel?
Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, в приложении нужно передать 3 файла, два из них изображения, третий пдф. Имена этих файлов записываются в БД. Мне нужно сделать две валидации для загружаемых файлов, а я никак не могу найти подобные примеры.

Валидация по уникальному имени (т.е. файлы с одинаковыми именами не должны загружаться и записываться в БД, тем более в БД поле имеет значение уникальности) пытался проверить по аналогии со строковыми полями через unique(model, column), но как и предполагал, не работает, т.к. файл передается не как один параметр строки
Валидация добавляемых изображений (чтобы в разные инпуты нельзя было добавить два одинаковых файла)

Подскажите как можно отвалидировать эту ситуацию?
